# Error in paramGrid in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am using paramGrid to fine tune my model parameters. Here is the following code.

```py
windowSize = 5
minCount = 10
vectorSize=300
maxIter= [10,100,1000]
regParam= [0.1,0.01]


paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(q1w2model.setWindowSize,windowSize) \
    .addGrid(q1w2model.setMinCount,minCount) \
    .addGrid(q2w2model.setWindowSize,windowSize) \
    .addGrid(q2w2model.setMinCount,minCount) \
     .addGrid(q1w2model.setVectorSize,vectorSize) \
    .addGrid(q2w2model.setVectorSize,vectorSize) \
    .addGrid(lr.setMaxIter,maxIter) \
    .addGrid(lr.setRegParam, regParam) \
    .build()


tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          trainRatio=0.8)



model = tvs.fit(train) # model is the model with combination of parameters that performed best
```

Following is the traceback call:

> File "/home/PycharmProjects/untitled1/quora_feaures_pyspark.py", line 406, in 
>       .addGrid(lr.setRegParam, regParam) \
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/ml/tuning.py", line 115, in build
>       return [dict(zip(keys, prod)) for prod in itertools.product(*grid_values)]
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

`ParamGridBuilder.add_grid` method expects an iterable data type where you are passing `windowSize`, `minCount`, and `vectorSize` as integers into `add_grid`.  You need to change those variables to be a list like your other grid search parameters to resolve the error.